# Paperclip original url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I need to get the file system url for the file uploaded by Paperclip. I tried doing this

```
ProjectAttachment.last.attachment.url
ProjectAttachment Load (0.6ms)

SELECT `project_attachments`.* FROM `project_attachments`
ORDER BY `project_attachments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1 => "/system/project_attachments/attachments/000/000/014/original/Updated_test_v1_2a.xlsx?1367191020"
```

Why is it adding `?1367191020` after the file? Is there a way to make sure that doesn't get added to URL?

Comment: It's just a time-stamp will not affect rendering the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [method documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L117-L147), a timestamp is added to the end of the url by default. So change your code to:

```
ProjectAttachment.last.attachment.url(:timestamp => false)
```